# C# Unity: sharing violation on path error even though i am using the using block which is supposed to close stream at the end of it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

C# Unity: sharing violation on path error even though i am using the using block which is supposed to close stream at the end of it.

This is the code

```
using (StreamReader SkinReader = new StreamReader(Application.dataPath + "/Memory of the game/SkinFile.txt")) 
        {
            Line = SkinReader.ReadToEnd();
            CheckedLine = true;
        }
        if (CheckedLine == true) 
        {
            if (Line == "0")
            {
                CheckedLine = false;
                Equip();
            }
            else if (Line == "1")
            {
                CheckedLine = false;
                Equip1();
            }
            else if (Line == "2")
            {
                CheckedLine = false;
                Debug.Log("wssssss");
                Equip2();
            }
            else if (Line == "3")
            {
                CheckedLine = false;
                Equip3();
            }
            else if (Line == "4")
            {
                CheckedLine = false;
                Equip4();
            }
            else if (Line == "5")
            {
                CheckedLine = false;
                Equip5();
            }
            else if (Line == "6")
            {
                CheckedLine = false;
                Equip6();
            }
        }
```

and after that a few lines down there is:

```
        using (StreamWriter SkinWriter = new StreamWriter(Application.dataPath + "/Memory of the game/SkinFile.txt"))
        {
            SkinWriter.Write("0");
        }
```

And i get this error at the Streamwriter, but I don't know why becouse shouldn't using streamreader close the file for using?

I should also mention that the Streamwriter is located in the Equip() function, but it is called UNDER the streamreader.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED THE PROBLEM:

I have another script where i just do:
`SkinReader = new StreamReader(Application.dataPath + "/Memory of the game/SkinFile.txt");`

And i never close it.

So for everyone having this issue, please check your other script!

Comment: So closing / disposing it worked like mentioned in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your last sentence pretty much sums up the error, you opened the stream while reading and then within that block, under Equip(), you are trying to open the same stream again for stream writing.

My recommendation would be to not nest your reading and writing capabilities with each other. First do the reading, and then after that, close the stream and then start the writing process depending on what you read.

Refactoring it would look something like:

```cs
// Decouple your reading and writing

// Reading part
using (StreamReader SkinReader = new StreamReader(Application.dataPath + "/Memory of the game/SkinFile.txt")) 
        {
            Line = SkinReader.ReadToEnd();
            CheckedLine = true;
        }

// Writing part
using (StreamWriter SkinWriter = new StreamWriter(Application.dataPath + "/Memory of the game/SkinFile.txt"))
    {
        if (CheckedLine == true) 
        {
            if (Line == "0")
            {
                CheckedLine = false;
                SkinWriter.Write("0");
            }
            else if (Line == "1")
            {
                CheckedLine = false;
                SkinWriter.Write("0");
            }
            else if (Line == "2")
            {
                CheckedLine = false;
                Debug.Log("wssssss");
                SkinWriter.Write("0");
            }
            else if (Line == "3")
            {
                CheckedLine = false;
                SkinWriter.Write("0");
            }
            else if (Line == "4")
            {
                CheckedLine = false;
                SkinWriter.Write("0");
            }
            else if (Line == "5")
            {
                CheckedLine = false;
                SkinWriter.Write("0");
            }
            else if (Line == "6")
            {
                CheckedLine = false;
                SkinWriter.Write("0");
            }
        }

           
    }
```

Of course the code can be made prettier with a switch statement or more but this is refactored so the error wont be shown.

Comment: but my if else block are not in streamreader but outside and under it (NOT IN USING)

Comment: @Tonza-S Oh I missed that, got confused because of the indentations. In this case, simply dispose your stream reader at the last line of that block like `SkinReader.Dispose()`. This makes sure its still not open when you start writing.

Comment: SkinReader.Dispose() doesn't work for me, and i also tried SkinReader.Close(), and it looks like it sometimes work and sometimes not, so maybe there's something else causing the error. TP95 thanks for all the help